# Python Eve, how to replace a 'dict' with a PATCH request

Tags: python, mongodb, eve

I am using Python Eve, which is awesome, however I ran into a problem and not sure if there is a solution.

I have a 'fields' dict in this schema:

```
'profiles': {
  'fields': {
    'type': 'dict',
    'default': {}
  }
}
```

I'd like to be able to PATCH update the 'fields' field, but the issue is that a PATCH request will never REMOVE any field inside 'fields', but I cannot use a PUT command or else all my other profile fields (not shown above) will disappear.

I tried using a subresource like this:

```
'profile-fields': {
  'schema': {
    'fields': {
      'type': 'dict',
      'default': {}
    }
  },
  'datasource': {
    'source': 'profiles',
    'projection': { 'fields': 1 }
  }
},
```

but as the Python Eve documentation states:

> Please note that POST and PATCH methods will still allow the whole schema to be manipulated
>   http://python-eve.org/config.html#multiple-api-endpoints-one-datasource

Anyone know of a way to do this?

For Example:

```
# Create a record
POST /api/profiles
{
  'name': 'Test',
  'fields': {
    'one': 1,
    'two': 2
  }
}
# => { _created: 'blah', _id: '123456' }

# then update fields with a PATCH request
PATCH /api/profiles/123456
{
  'fields': {
    'three': 3,
    'four': 4
  }
}

# then get the updated record
GET /api/profiles/123456
# RESPONSE
{
  '_id': '123456',
  'name': 'Test',
  'fields': {
    'one': 1,
    'two': 2,
    'three': 3,
    'four': 4
  }
}
```

I have just conceded to using a PUT request and sending the entire object back again, which is ok I guess, just thought there might be a way to do this.

Comment: hello, can you post an example of before/after of what you expect the dict would be? Can't you just replace the entire dict when patching?

Comment: That's basically the issue, when you PATCH, it will only overwrite key/values in the dict, it will not remove any keys NOT in the request.

Comment: I updated the content with a representative example code

Comment: But do you want to remove the old values, or just add new ones without changing old values?

Comment: Was there ever a solution other than put, having the same calamity?